# How to make text not wrap in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, configuration, customization

I have the output from a command in `gnome-terminal`, but there is too much text currently so it is wrapping, but the wrapping means that it is much harder for me to read the output because of the nature of it. So I was wondering if there is any way to make the output, or perhaps even all the text, not wrap in `gnome-terminal`?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: You could pipe it to `nano`, since it supports not wrapping.

Comment: @AndroidDev: I wouldn't actually say that that really answers my question, I want to do it with all output, and not just output, but also with commands I type. This just gives examples with applications, not how to do it more centrally in `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Do you expect a horizontal scrollbar to appear? If so, gnome-terminal does not support it. You need to use a helper application (such as `less`) that allows you to scroll a file's contents or a command's output horizontally.

Comment: @egmont: Are there any Terminals which do support it?

Comment: There were a few experimental ones, perhaps `finalterm` (no longer maintained) if I recall correctly (not sure). I've never tried any. The concept is inherently broken. Apps running inside terminals do have the notion of terminal width and often paint stuff accordingly (e.g. text editors), and might legally "overflow" to the next line (print stuff spanning across the right margin and expect to appear in the next row). So I cannot imagine reasonable behavior of these apps inside such a terminal.